# Cannot switch to console anymore after using Alt_R as mod4

Tags: xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, console, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I'd like to use the right ALT key as 'mod4' (most notably because, by default, the 'awesome' window manager is using mod4 as a modifier for most WM commands and I like that idea a lot).

However I've got an issue: as soon as I add:

```
xmodmap -e 'add mod4 = Alt_R'
```

then I cannot use, say, CTRL+ALT+F2 to switch from X to a text console.

(note that I always used left ALT to do that, not right ALT: actually before assigning right ALT to mod4 I was never ever using that key)

It's really a problem with the shortcut / modifiers since that I can still switch from X to a text console by using, say, the *chvt* command.  For example the following always works fine:

```
chvt 1
```

As soon as I clear mod4:

```
xmodmap -e 'clear mod4'
```

I can use `CTRL+ALT+F2` (left ALT once again) to switch to my text console.

But of course then I don't get the nice default mod4+... 'awesome' shortcuts.

So basically I can either use right ALT as mod4 and have awesome work fine *or* I can clear mod4 (not assigning right ALT to any modifier) and be able to use CTRL+ALT+F2 to swith to a text console.

But I cannot do both.

Do any of you know why configuring right ALT as mod4 prevents CTRL+left ALT+F2 from switching to a text console?

Here's the full *xmodmap* (when CTRL+left ALT+F2 is *not* working):

```
shift   Shift_L (0x32), Shift_R (0x3e)
lock
control Control_L (0x25), Control_L (0x42), Control_R (0x69)
mod1    Alt_L (0x40), Alt_L (0xcc), Metal_L (0xcd)
mod2    Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3    
mod4    Alt_R (0x6c)
mod5    ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c), Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Once again clearing that mod4 and I can switch to a text console fine...

I'm not interested in using another setup than:

- right ALT as mod4
- mod4+... as shortcuts for awesome
- CTRL+ALT+F{1,9} to switch to a different VT

Now of course I can use "chvt" to switch to a text console, but that wouldn't work that great should my X be stuck.

I always like to have the possibility to switch to a text console to, say, kill X if it's stuck (been doing that since the early days of slackware).

Comment: What does right alt produce in `xev`? Also [see this answer on Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70931/how-to-set-right-alt-to-work-as-a-winsuper-key)

Comment: @jasonwryan: xev says *keysym 0xffea, Alt_R*  (checking the ask Ubuntu thinggy)

Comment: Then I would try adding the `remove` line to explicitly offload whatever it is initially mapped to before assigning it to `mod4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When trying to use similar window managers (xwem, ratpoison) for the first time, I first also tried to follow the setup instructions involving `xmodmap` to get a modifiier key for the window manager, but then I felt that using `xmodmap` in my system causes some mess, because in my system (an ALTLinux distro) attention has always been paid to multilingual keyboard configuration via XKB, rather than via `xmodmap`.

So, I found an XKB option to label the key I wanted as "Hyper", and then used the "Hyper" modifier in the configuration for xwem or ratpoison.

In my case, the option to `setxkbmap` is:

```
 -option altwin:hyper_win
```

and here is the comment I've saved on the occasion of adding it to my setup:

> xemacs-xwem uses Hyper, so I found this predefined XKB map (in
>   xkb/symbols/altwin), which uses the WIN keys.
>
> Perhaps later I'll make up another XKB map for me, say, using the
>   right Control as Hyper (that will force my hand to use the right
>   Control--now my hand just ignores it).
>
> I thought it's a more clean way to get myself a Hyper key through XKB
>   rather than through xmodmap (as described in XWEM docs), because:
>
> 1. xmodmap configuration of modifier keys seems not to be nice w.r.t.
>      the way it forces one to present one's intentions: one must say
>      something about arbitrarily numbered modifier bits, but I don't want
>      to think about these technical things: I need merely a *"Hyper"*
>      modifier, not some obscure manipulations with the internals! In
>      xmodmap, I'd need to give 2 or even 3 obscure statements to achieve
>      the result, although logically this is a single wish and operation.
>      (One xmodmap statement would not be enough, cf. XEmacs' warnings
>      (FIXME: insert!) if you map Control_R to a modN; there are some
>      technical constraints.)
> 2. one is told stories that XKB and xmodmap don't play well together,
>      so that not all X programs will work nicely and coherently if you mix
>      them (I must give a link here, FIXME).

Here is the relevant definition from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/altwin`, if someone is interested:

```
partial modifier_keys 
xkb_symbols "hyper_win" {
    key <LWIN> {    [   Hyper_L         ]   };
    key <RWIN> {    [   Hyper_R         ]   };
    modifier_map Mod4   { Hyper_L, Hyper_R };
};
```

Comment: Ivan Zakharyasch: thanks a lot...  I got your xmodmap / xkb point!  I ended up doing something very similar, only using xkb.  No more xmodmap here : )